# SQL separate row for each date between 2 dates

Tags: sql, db2

We have a Begin_date and End_date column and I need to have a separate row for each date between the two. For example if begin_date = 11/25/2010 and end_date = 11/26/2010 then it should look like

key:   Closed Date:
01     11/25/2010
01     11/26/2010

Comment: Do you want all days between two dates? Your example data is consecutive... if your end_date was 11/27/10 then would you want three rows?

Comment: All dates between are needed, I just used that example for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

One common method is to create a calendar table of dates and join to it on your criteria. The space to store the data is small and the overhead is low compared to an iterative generation method for every time you want the data.

so in your joins you would add the CalendarTable with Date >= Start_Date and Date <= End_Date